# What does '~' mean when debug in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, tilde

Here is my method:

```
public static void send(byte[] packet)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": ");
    foreach (byte b in packet)
    {
        Console.Write(b.ToString("X2") + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    if (connected)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Socket.Send(packet);        
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't send packet");
        }
    }        
}
```

Here is caller

```
public void addPacket(PacketProcessed packet) 
{
    int messageEvent = (int)Event.Type.Normal;
    int speed = 0;
    foreach (MessageProcessed message in packet.messages)
    {
        if ((currentlyEvent & (int)Event.Type.Speed) == (int)Event.Type.Speed)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(message.xSpeed) >= this.speedLimit - this.speedLimit * 0.1)
            {
                messageEvent |= (int)Event.Type.Speed;
                speed = Math.Max(speed, (int)Math.Abs(message.xSpeed));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Math.Abs(message.xSpeed) >= this.speedLimit)
            {
                messageEvent |= (int)Event.Type.Speed;
                speed = Math.Max(speed, (int)Math.Abs(message.xSpeed));
            }
        }
    }
    this.currentlyEvent = messageEvent;
    if (this.currentlyEvent != historyEvent)
    {
        byte[] bb = ProtocolBuilder.buildProtocal(0xE0 + location, currentlyEvent, (byte)speed);
        TCPTalker.send(bb);    // <--- This line call above (send) method.
    }
    historyEvent = currentlyEvent;
    packetStorage.Add(packet);
}
```

Output look like

```
~4/10/2013 3:10:59 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 44 E6 02 42 
~4/10/2013 3:11:00 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E6 00 88 
4/10/2013 3:11:00 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 45 E6 02 41 
~~4/10/2013 3:11:04 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E6 00 88 
~4/10/2013 3:11:05 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3C E3 02 4D 
~4/10/2013 3:11:13 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
4/10/2013 3:11:13 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 41 E2 02 49 
~~4/10/2013 3:11:18 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E3 00 8B 
~4/10/2013 3:11:19 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 40 E6 02 46 
~4/10/2013 3:11:24 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3D E3 02 4C 
~4/10/2013 3:11:25 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E6 00 88 
4/10/2013 3:11:25 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E3 00 8B 
~~4/10/2013 3:11:26 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3D E3 02 4C 
~4/10/2013 3:11:30 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
~4/10/2013 3:11:38 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 42 E6 02 44 
~4/10/2013 3:11:44 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E3 00 8B 
~4/10/2013 3:11:47 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3C E2 02 4E 
~4/10/2013 3:11:50 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E6 00 88 
~4/10/2013 3:11:56 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
4/10/2013 3:11:56 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3D E2 02 4D 
~~4/10/2013 3:11:57 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
~4/10/2013 3:11:59 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 3C E2 02 4E 
~4/10/2013 3:12:01 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
~4/10/2013 3:12:05 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 46 E2 02 44 
~4/10/2013 3:12:12 PM: 7E 00 1A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3A 00 00 00 00 00 E2 00 8C 
~
```

I saw '~' appear before my debug string become appear.
Sometime output window show ~ then ~ then my debug string look like ~~4/10/2013 3:12:01 PM: 7E 00 ...

What does '~' mean?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't writing it yourself somewhere else in your program?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a short but complete program which definitely doesn't contain any other calls to Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @Jon `Console.Write` rather than `Console.WriteLine`, probably - since it isn't line-terminated

Comment: @MarcGravell: Very true.

Comment: Thanks nvoigt!
I've already checked it. But nothing found.

Answer (score 2):

It has no predefined meaning whatsoever. I would check your other code for calls to `Console.Write`; at a *complete guess*, maybe check any finalizers - maybe they have some output, i.e. something like:

```
class Foo {
    ~Foo() {
        #if DEBUG
        // show that I got collected; hey I know - let's write to the console...
        // that won't confuse *anyone*
        Console.Write("~");
        #endif
    }
}
```

But a global search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) for `~` should find it.

Comment: Thanks Marc Gravell !
I've already done it. But nothing found.

Comment: @Pruk and for `Console.Write`? Also: what additional libraries (if any) are you using? is it possible it is coming from one of them? Here's the thing: .NET doesn't add `~` to stdout for no reason. It is coming from somewhere in the application (your code, or a dll) that is electively doing this.

Comment: sorry but my project have no additional libraries. I'm using VC# 2010 Express. hope this information help..